# Ajuda com unlink no PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Estou tentando migrar o MYSQL para o PDO, e me deparei com um problema com o Unlink.

Com o código abaixo eu consigo fazer o UPDATE na tabela Banner do BD, e também armazeno o novo arquivo na pasta de destino (img_banner), mas não substituindo o arquivo anterior na pasta de destino.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['banner'])){
$codigo = $_GET['codigo'];
$imagem = $_POST['imagem'];
$sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE banner SET imagem = ? WHERE codigo = ?';
$dados = array($imagem, $codigo);

$pasta = '../img_banner/';
if (isset($_POST['banner'])){
$check = @$_POST['apagar'];
foreach($check as $imagem){
$delcheck = $sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE banner SET imagem = ? WHERE codigo = ?' or die (mysql_error()); 
unlink($pasta.'/'.$imagem);
if ($delcheck >= '1'){
echo 'Imagem deletada com sucesso!';
}else{
echo 'Erro ao deletar imagem, tente novamente!';
}}}}
?>

<?php include 'upload_banner.php'; ?>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input size="1" type="hidden" name="codigo" value="<?php echo $codigo?>" readonly>
    <input type="hidden" type="checkbox" name="apagar[]" value="<?php echo $imagem ?>" checked readonly>
    <label>Selecione uma nova imagem:</label><br />
    <input type="file" name="imagem[]" accept="image/*" ><br />
    <input type="submit" name="banner" value="Atualizar">
</form>
```

Com esse co´digo esta me apresentando os seguintes erros abaixo:

Erro 01:

Notice: Undefined index:imagem in C:\wamp\www\Commerce\admin\edit_banner__inicial-upd.php on line 41

Erro 02:

Notice: unlink(../img_banner//); Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\Commerce\admin\edit_banner_inicial-upd.php on line 53

Qualquer ajuda será muito bem vinda.;)

Answer (score 0):

Olá, consegui resolver o problema, e posto abaixo o código funcionando sem erros para futuras dúvidas dos amigos.

```
<?php
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM banner WHERE codigo = $codigo") or die(mysql_error());
    $sql->execute();
    foreach($sql->fetchAll() as $res);

    if(isset($_POST['banner'])){
    $codigo = $_GET['codigo'];
    $sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE banner SET imagem = $imagem WHERE codigo = $codigo';
    $dados = array($codigo);

    $pasta = '../img_banner';
    if (isset($_POST['banner'])){
    $check = @$_POST['apagar'];
    foreach($check as $imagem){
    $delcheck = $sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE banner SET imagem = $imagem WHERE codigo = $codigo' or die (mysql_error()); 
    unlink($pasta.'/'.$imagem);
    if ($delcheck >= '1'){
    echo 'Imagem deletada com sucesso!';
    }else{
    echo 'Erro ao deletar imagem, tente novamente!';
    }}}}
?>

<?php include 'upload_banner.php'; ?>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input size="1" type="hidden" name="codigo" value="<?php echo $res['codigo']; ?>" readonly>
    <input type="hidden" type="checkbox" name="apagar[]" value="<?php echo $res['imagem']; ?>" checked readonly>
    <label>Selecione uma nova imagem:</label><br />
    <input type="file" name="imagem[]" accept="image/*" ><br />
    <input type="submit" name="banner" value="Atualizar">
</form>
```

Até a próxima.;)